# Undefined variable while creating sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to create sessions in codeigniter and followed the steps as usual but while displaying session data at once i am getting error undefined variable email i try to find out mistake but no success

//controller Logincontroller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
print_r( debug_backtrace() );
//ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
//ini_set('max_execution_time', 3000);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class LoginController extends CI_Controller
{

     public function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->library('session');
          $this->load->helper('form');
          $this->load->helper('url');
          $this->load->helper('html');
          $this->load->database();
          $this->load->library('form_validation');

     }

     public function index()
     {
            //load the login model
          $this->load->model('login_model');
        //  $qry=$this->login_model->validate();



          //get the posted values
          $username = $this->input->post("username");
          $password = $this->input->post("password");

          //set validations
          $this->form_validation->set_rules("username", "username", "trim|required");
          $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "password", "trim|required");

          if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
          {
               //validation fails
               redirect('Homecontroller/index');  //make new controller for loading a form again
               echo "Validation fails"; // even for no name and passwrd
          }
          else
          {
               //validation succeeds
               if ($this->input->post('submit') == "Login")
               {
                    //check if username and password is correct
                    $usr_result = $this->login_model->get_user($username, $password);
                    if ($usr_result > 0) //active user record is present
                    {
                         //set the session variables
                        // $sessiondata = array(
                            //  'username' => $username,
                              //'loginuser' => TRUE
                         //);
                         $this->login_model->set_session($username,$email);//line 58
                         print_r($this->session->all_userdata());  //to check
                         return $username;
                         redirect("Site/member_area");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Invalid username and password!</div>');
                         redirect('Homecontroller/index');
                    }
               }
               else
               {
                    redirect('login/home3');
               }
          }
     }


}?>
```

//this is my model login_model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login_model extends CI_Model
{
     function __construct()
     {
          // Call the Model constructor
          parent::__construct();

     }

     //get the username & password from tbl_usrs
     public function get_user($usr, $pwd)
     {    
          $sql = "select * from tbl_usrs where username = '" . $usr . "' and password = '" .$pwd . "' ";
          $query = $this->db->query($sql);
          return $query->num_rows();
     }

             public function set_session($username,$email) {
                $sql="SELECT id FROM tbl_usrs WHERE username='".$username."' LIMIT 1 ";
                $result=$this->db->query($sql);
                $row=$result->row();


                $sess_data=array (

                    'id'=>$row->id,
                    'username'=>$username,
                    'email'=>$email,//line 30
                    'is_login'=>TRUE
                    );

            $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);




            } //set_seesion function ends

    }?>
```

this is what i am getting

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1438028278 [id] => 4 [username] => aman [email] => [is_login] => 1 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with codeigniter but i think the problem is here

```
 public function set_session($username,$email) {
    $sql="SELECT id FROM tbl_usrs WHERE username='".$username."' LIMIT 1 ";
    $result=$this->db->query($sql);
    $row=$result->row();


    $sess_data=array (

        'id'=>$row->id,
        'username'=>$username,
        'email'=>$email,
        'is_login'=>TRUE
        );

$this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
```

In above code, you are only fetching `id` from database, so i think it should be as follow, fetch both `id` and `email`

```
 public function set_session($username,$email) {
    $sql="SELECT id, email FROM tbl_usrs WHERE username='".$username."' LIMIT 1 ";
    $result=$this->db->query($sql);
    $row=$result->row();


    $sess_data=array (

        'id'=>$row->id,
        'username'=>$username,
        'email'=>$row->email,
        'is_login'=>TRUE
        );

$this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
```

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshi, as i said, I'm not very familiar with `codeigniter` and just here to help in anyway possible and may b i learn tit bits of `codeigniter` too this way. :)

Comment: even i am in starting phase of learning Codeigniter and i am also having same problem from 2 days but this give me some hint where i can be wrong

Comment: @Optimmus, you need to check the `SELECT` query, i put `email` in it, may b its wrong col name, may b in table you have different col name for `email` and after you may also need to change this `$row->email` according to correct col name.

Comment: @Optimmus can you copy paste the error and narrow down to the line where it is referring?

Comment: Undefined variable: email

Filename: controllers/LoginController.php

 Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\ko\application\models\Login_model.php on line 30

Comment: yeah i see the error originated here 'email'=>$row->email,

Comment: @Optimmus in you code did you change this `'email'=>$email,` to this `'email'=>$row->email,` ?

Comment: sir i make necessary changes whatever you have mentioned

Comment: it worked now instead of making seprate function set_session i have stored all session data above as 

if ($usr_result > 0) //active user record is present
                    {
                         //set the session variables
                        // $sessiondata = array(
                            //  'username' => $username,
                              //'loginuser' => TRUE
                         //);

Comment: that's great, happy i be any help at all. happy coding.